# C++/CLI string interop

Tags: c#, wpf, string, interop, c++-cli

I am working on a C++/CLI wrapper for a native c++ class. The C++/CLI wrapper is being used in a WPF application. I have encountered a weird problem when trying to marshal strings.

The WPF application passes a `System::String` object to my wrapper. The wrapper then converts the `System::String` to a `std::string` that the native class expects. This all goes fine, but once I pass the string to the native object, it is empty.

Here is some relevant code

**WPF Event Handler (C#)**

```
private void tbInputConfig_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _OrionBasicApp.ConfigTemplateFile = tbInputConfig.Text;
}
```

**Property In Wrapper Class (C++/CLI)**

```
void BasicApp::ConfigTemplateFile::set(String ^value)
{
    std::string val = marshal_as<std::string>(value);
    _NativeApp->setConfigTemplateFile(val);
}
```

**Native Code (C++)**

```
void Basic_App::setConfigTemplateFile(const std::string& template_file)
{
   m_gParams.configTemplateFile = template_file;
}
```

So when I break in the WPF app and trace using the debugger, the String objects look fine, the `std::string val` marshaling looks good, but the parameter `template_file` in the `setConfigFile` function is an empty string. When I step out of the native function, I can see that the `std::string val` variable still looks fine.

I have tried using `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` function, it produces the same result. I have tried changing the native function to take copy of the string instead of a reference, this produces an exception about an invalid block of memory (if requested I will post the exact message). I have tried allocating the string on the heap, no luck.

Now for the kicker: The native code was compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, and the wrapper + wpf code was compiled with 2010. I hope this is not the problem because it will not be easy for us to migrate either codebase to the other version.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I was able to switch the native code over to visual studio 2010 and this did fix the problem. (why must microsoft make my life so difficult?) While I did make the system build, the lead on the project is giving me MAJOR hassles about this solution (he is concerned that it may not run correctly or that we will have to switch over dependent libraries).

SO is there a solution to this problem that doesn't force me to switch visual studio version?

Comment: Is your C++ being compiled as UNICODE, MBCS, or ANSI ?

Comment: Good question I forgot to add this info. The native code is using the MultiByte charset. I have tried the C++/CLI layer in both Unicode and MultiByte and it makes no difference for my problem

Comment: How are you wrapping the native code?  Is the native code in one DLL and the wrapper in a separate DLL or are they linked into a single DLL?

Comment: The native code is in a separate dll built in visual studio 2009. The C++/CLI is compiled to its own assembly dll from VS2010. The WPF application is compiled to its own assembly exe also from 2010. The theory being that this way each component is easily consumable by different sources (For example, some fully native command line based tests were written for the native layer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing C++ objects across DLL boundaries is a bad idea.  `std::string` is not the same type, layout, or implementation, which is causing your problem.

If you pass either a BSTR (`SysStringAlloc` et al) or raw `char*` across the DLL boundary, and convert to `std::string` inside the native code instead of in the wrapper, your problem will go away.

This problem is not specific to .NET or C++/CLI.  Any attempt to pass `std::string` instances to your native DLL from any other compiler version will fail.

Example fix:

```
void BasicApp::ConfigTemplateFile::set(String ^value)
{
    std::string val = marshal_as<std::string>(value);
    _NativeApp->setConfigTemplateFile(val.c_str(), val.size());
}

void Basic_App::setConfigTemplateFile(const char* template_file_content, size_t template_file_length)
{
   m_gParams.configTemplateFile = std::string(template_file_content, template_file_length);
}
```

Comment: Interesting to know that std::string changed that much between versions. I ended up doing something similar as a workaround, since it seems there is no other way I am giving you the answer

Comment: @Max, it doesn't mean `std::string` changed at all.  Different compilers are allowed to compile the exact same code in incompatible ways, as long as the overall behavior is met within each module taken in isolation.  Only POD (or in C++11, standard-layout) types can safely be passed between compilers.

Comment: But yeah, for `std::string` specifically, there are things like small-string optimizations, or use of different allocators, that do change between compilers.

Comment: Right right, that makes perfect sense. I guess my (clearly wrong) assumption was that close visual studio versions would be compatible

Comment: @Max: Ah, that's a reasonable question, but definitely would have been worth asking about instead of just assuming.  The reality is somewhat worse... even the same compiler version with different compile options can be incompatible.  And with some compile options, you can't pass objects between DLLs at all, even when the same compiler and options were used for all of them (DLL-local allocators).